# MySQL Join Query

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm sure this is an easy one but nethertheless I'm struggling. Here is what I have:

```
tbl_user 
======== 
id 
name 
etc 


tbl_jobs 
======== 
id 
job_details 


tbl_job_applications 
====================  
user_id 
job_id 
application_details
applied_date
```

The relations are:

- user -> job_applications (1 to many)
- jobs -> job_applications (1 to many)

All I want to do is get the list of job applications for a given user, along with the job_details field from the jobs table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, job_details, application_details, applied_date from
  tbl_job_applications a,
  tbl_jobs j,
  tbl_user u
where a.user_id=u.id and j.id = a.job_id
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work.

```
SELECT          [tbl_user].[Name]
               ,[tbl_jobs].[job_details]
               ,[tbl_job_applicaitons].[application_details]
FROM            [tbl_user]
INNER JOIN      [tbl_jobs_applications]
ON            [tbl_jobs_applications].[user_id]=[tbl_user].[id]
INNER JOIN      [tbl_jobs]
ON            [tbl_jobs].[id]=[tbl_job_applications].[job_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.application_details, a.applied_date, j.job_details
from tbl_job_applications a 
left join tbl_jobs j on a.job_id = j.id 
where a.user_id = user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.name, ja.application_details, ja.applied_date, j.job_details
    from tbl_user u
        inner join tbl_job_applications ja
            on u.id = ja.user_id
        inner join tbl_jobs j
            on ja.job_id = j.id
    where u.id = @YourUserID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
j.job_details,
a.application_details,
a.applied_date
FROM
tbl_job_applications a inner join tbl_jobs j on j.id = a.job_id and a.user_id = @user_id
```